# How to release the deleted shard storage in InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb

I changed the retention policy of a database to keep data only for one day and after that, I dropped all shards created from `autogen` RP, but InfluxDB still takes a huge part of the storage on `/var/lib/influxdb/data/<DB NAME>/_series` folder and it's increasing continuously. 
How can I release the storage related to the deleted points?

Comment: Sounds weird! There is an issue on Github repository of influxdb and no one talked on it! https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/10560